# What Taylor series has the sum of $-ln\left ( \frac{8}{5} \right )$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

How to compute the Taylor series which has the sum $-ln\left ( \frac{8}{5} \right )$. Is this done by finding the series for $-ln\left (x \right )$ centered around the point $a=\frac{8}{5}$?

Comment: You could use the Taylor series of the constant function: $f(x) = -\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)$, at $a$ equal to any real number.

Comment: Do Taylor series for $-\ln(1-x)$ (aka Mercator series) at $x=-\frac{3}{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ln (1+x)= \int \frac {1}{1+x}= \int 1-x+x^2-x^3+....=$$

$$x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...$$

$$\ln (8/5) = \ln (1+3/5)= (3/5)-(3/5)^2/2 +(3/5)^3/3-...$$

$$-\ln (8/5) = - (3/5)+(3/5)^2/2-(3/5)^3/3+...$$